# NPM making HTTP requests for private git repo accessible over SSH

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, gitlab

I am using a private git repo as a npm package. The git repo is only accessible over SSH. I am able to download the package using SSH but upon intercepting HTTP calls, I can see npm is making http requests to the repository to download a tar file.

The HTTP request parameters are something like this,

```
URL: https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo/repository/archive.tar.gz?ref=0269e4108eccf7848ba3c6722338a26b6228570c

Headers:
npm-auth-type: web
npm-command: install
pacote-pkg-id: <PACKAGE_ID>
pacote-req-type: tarball
pacote-version: 15.1.3
user-agent: npm/9.6.7 node/v20.3.0 darwin arm64 workspaces/false
```

As the repository is only accessible over SSH, these additional unauthenticated requests are causing rate limiting for the repository. How can I configure NPM so that it does not make those additional http requests for the private repository hosted over SSH only?

Here's an example of the `package.json` file,

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "~5.1.0",
    "@myorg/something": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git#0269e4108eccf7848ba3c6722338a26b6228570c",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16 <19",
    "npm": ">=6 <=9"
  }
}
```

Here's my `.npmrc`,

```
engine-strict = false
fund = false
lockfile-version = "3"
update-notifier = false
```

I tried the following `.npmrc` configs,

```
fetch-retries=0
git-fetch-with-cli=true
git-protocol="ssh"
```

But they do not seem to work.